# PyQt code doesnt work when it's inside the class

Tags: python, class, pyqt

Recently I have created an simple `PyQt` based app. All it have to do is to make a system tray icon. The problem is that I can see the application is running, however no tray icon is being made. When I move the tray icon code outside the class its *working* fine. **So why is the class a problem here?**

**My code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class myApp(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.createTrayIcon()

    def createTrayIcon(self):
        self.trayIconMenu = QtGui.QMenu()
        self.trayIconMenu.addAction("Close", lambda : exit(1))

        self.trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon()
        self.trayIcon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(r"icon.png"))
        self.trayIcon.setToolTip("Tooltip")
        self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.trayIconMenu)
        self.trayIcon.show()
        self.trayIcon.showMessage("Title", u"Content")

myApp()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When you "move the tray icon code outside the class", where do you move it to?

Comment: Also, why are you creating a `QWidget` subclass that doesn't appear to represent any kind of widget?

Comment: @abarnert Just a typo, this doesn't matter. I am now using `QtCore.QThread` instead.

Comment: If you are now using a QThread, please make sure you aren't actually doing **anything** with the GUI from within the thread (Qt GUI objects can only be created and accessed from the main thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't store the object created in the call to `myApp()` in a variable, it is garbage collected by Python at some point. Your tray icon may thus be visible for a very brief moment, but will be cleaned up and disappear at some point (which is what you are seeing).

As long as you do `myapp = myApp()` instead, you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have your forget this line at main ?

```
.
.
.
objectMyApp = myApp()
objectMyApp.show() # Or don't show please comment this in.
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Problem is your create object but not put in variable. It better if your put in variable.